# Sort a vector c++

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, 2d

I am trying to sort a 2D vector with the type:

```
vector<pair<char, double>> output;
```

I am trying to arrange them from the highest to lowest double value and only displaying the top 5. This is what I am trying to do:

```
sort(output.begin(), output.end());
```

But this sort is not working properly for me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You probably want to define your own comparison functor.

Comment: Define "not working properly".  Show us code.

Comment: Another possibility...swap the char-double pair with a double-char pair, and then directly sort it..extra +O(N) time which is irrelevant because sorting is O(NlogN) and extra O(N) memory...if you can afford it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `std::sort` will use the less-than comparison operator for the elements of the container, which will perform am lexicographical comparison using the `char` first and then the `double`.

You can use your own ordering function/functor that orders based on the pair's `double` element only:

```
bool cmp(const std::pair<char, double>& lhs, 
         const std::pair<char, double>& rhs)
{
  return lhs.second > rhs.second;
}
```

then

```
std::vector<std::pair<char, double>> output = ....;
sort(output.begin(), output.end(), cmp);
```

See [working demo here](http://ideone.com/6lTwAR).

Comment: Error 1 error C3867: 'CaesarCypher::cmp': function call missing argument list; use '&CaesarCypher::cmp' to create a pointer to member

Comment: @user977154 you're doing something wrong! The `cmp` function is a non-member function.

Comment: Error 2 error C2780: 'void std::sort(_RanIt,_RanIt)' : expects 2 arguments - 3 provided

Comment: Even after making it a non member function it does not compile

Comment: @user977154 Either you are doing something else wrong, or your std library installation is broken. See [this compiling demo](http://ideone.com/6lTwAR).

Comment: Thank you, I will look around for errors in my code.

Answer (score 2):

As Violet said, you may want to include your own comparison function:

> ```
> class compare
> {
> public:
>     bool operator() (std::pair<char, int> const& p1,
>                     std::pair<char, int> const& p2) const
>     {
>         // perform logic here
>     }
> } Predicate;
> ```

`std::sort` uses `operator <` to compare the elements, and sorts them accordingly. It has an extra optional parameter for the comparsion functor, which we can include like this:

> ```
> std::sort(output.begin(), output.end(), Predicate);
> ```

Note that this can also be done using a lambda in C++11.

Comment: I'm not sure, but the comparator has not to be a thing (function, lambda, functor) with signature `bool(const value_type& , const value_type&)`? I think you should write `operator()` instead of `operator<`

Comment: @Manu343726 That is exactly what this is. `std::sort` will call `compare::operator <` internally.

Comment: mmmm no, is not a callable object, you have defined comparison operator only.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a comparison operator between the `pair<char, double>` operands.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're using a vector of pairs? In other words, does the order in which the elements are stored internally really matter to you? If not, you're probably better off using  a `map<double,char>` with a reverse iterator to get the last 5 elements sorted by double value.